# Get multiple selections from Text

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Is there a way to make multiple selections in the Text widget, something like this:

[image]

and then extract them all? This code below only gets one selection:

```
self.text.get(SEL_FIRST, SEL_LAST)
```

Comment: i think this will not work. just think about selecting the first and then press a key to store for example. just try to face the problem with another approach.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing.  You could also tag selections with a new 'selected' tag, with it own foreground/background colors, so users could see what they have already selected.  A 'Done' button would then clear the 'selected' tags.